# A word whose suffix is the prefix for another word, so you can combine them?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, neologisms

I'm trying to think of words to be used for usernames and I noticed people sometimes take a word whose suffix matches the prefix of another word and combine them. Noteworthy examples:

- disarmpit
- bartenderizer
- cobwebsite

Is there a word for this type of made up words?

Comment: Not related to the question, but note that there is no such word as _thats_: the possessive form of the subordinator _that_ is _whose_. I’ve fixed this in your question, and I’ve also removed the last bit asking people to make up words for the concept, since that’s too broad and subjective to be considered on topic here. Other than that, +1 for an interesting question! I’m not aware of a word for this, but there probably is one.

Comment: This is known in the trade as [Haplology](https://www.google.com/search?q=Haplology), and the standard classroom example is probly _tragicomedy_ from _tragico-_ plus _comedy_. (The recursive mnemonic for Haplology is _Haplogy_)

Comment: It seems that Haplology is similar, but more general a term than what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to find words that just have a syllable omitted. I would like a term that I could search and get examples like the ones in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On game shows like NPR's [Ask Me Another](https://www.npr.org/programs/ask-me-another/), where many of their games require contestants to come up with combinations like this (sometimes they're single words, sometimes phrases), I think they call them "mash-ups".

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. They even have single word ones like unicornbread. You're the best Barmar, thanks.